# Enterprise Library Logging - Visual Studio - MONO - MacOSX - NotImplementedException

Tags: c#, .net, logging, mono, enterprise-library

I'm trying new VisualStudio for Mac (Mono 6.0.0.296) with With Microsoft Enterprise Library 6.0.1304. Unfortunatly im not able to use it since an "NotImplementedException" is raised.

I have been using Enterprise Library for many years but in Visual Studio (Windows Env.) and it is great but when i tried to use the same under mono everything seems not working.

After some search i can see that mscorlib.dll for MONO dows not support WindowsIdentity "User" Property.

mscorlib.dll (4.0.0.0 - MONO)

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[MonoTODO ("not implemented")]
[ComVisible (false)]
public SecurityIdentifier User {
    get {
        throw new NotImplementedException ();
    }
}
```

Application:

```
public static void Main (string [] args) 
{
    LogWriter logWriter = new LogWriterFactory ().Create ();
    Logger.SetLogWriter (logWriter, false);         
    logWriter.Write ("Application is working", "General", 5, 2000, TraceEventType.Information);         
}
```

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true" />  
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" 
                        tracingEnabled="false" 
                        defaultCategory="General"  
                        logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="false">    
    <listeners>  
        <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" 
             type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"        
             listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  
             fileName="RollingFlatFile.log"  
             footer="----------------------------------" 
             formatter="Text Formatter"  
             header="" rollInterval="Day"  
             traceOutputOptions="DateTime, Timestamp" 
             filter="All" />          
    </listeners>  
    <formatters>  
        <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"  
             template="Timestamp: {timestamp(local)}{newline}  
                       Message: {message}{newline}  
                       Category: {category}{newline}  
                       Priority: {priority}{newline}  
                       Severity: {severity}"  
             name="Text Formatter" />  
    </formatters>  
    <categorySources>  
        <add switchValue="All" autoFlush="true" name="General">  
            <listeners>  
                <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />    
            </listeners>  
        </add>  
    </categorySources>  
    <specialSources>  
        <allEvents switchValue="All" name="All Events">  
            <listeners>  
                <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />  
            </listeners>  
        </allEvents>  
        <notProcessed switchValue="All" name="Unprocessed Category">  
            <listeners>  
                <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />  
            </listeners>  
        </notProcessed>  
        <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">  
            <listeners>  
                <add name="Rolling Flat File Trace Listener" />  
            </listeners>  
        </errors>  
    </specialSources>  
  </loggingConfiguration>  
</configuration>
```

Error tracked into the file:

Timestamp: 12/07/2019 16:36:11

Message: Processing of the message failed. See summary information below for more information. Should this problem persist, stop the service and check the configuration file(s) for possible error(s) in the configuration of the categories and sinks.

## Summary for Enterprise Library Distributor Service:

--> 
Message: 
Timestamp: 12/07/2019 14:36:11
Message: Application is working
Category: General
Priority: 5
EventId: 2000
Severity: Information
Title:
Machine: MacBook-Pro-di-John
App Domain: F.B.Library.exe
ProcessId: Unable to read intrinsic property.  Error message: GetCurrentProcessId
Process Name: Unable to read intrinsic property.  Error message: GetModuleHandle
Thread Name: 
Win32 ThreadId:Unable to read intrinsic property.  Error message: GetCurrentThreadId
Extended Properties: 
--> MachineName: MacBook-Pro-di-John
--> TimeStamp: 12/07/2019 14:36:11
--> FullName: Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35
--> AppDomainName: F.B.Library.exe
--> WindowsIdentity: jfk

## Exception Information Details:

Exception Type: System.NotImplementedException
Message: The method or operation is not implemented.
Data: System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite: System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity GetCurrent(Boolean)
HelpLink: NULL
Source: mscorlib
HResult: -2147467263

## StackTrace Information Details:

at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent (System.Boolean ifImpersonating) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Principal/WindowsIdentity.cs:165 
  at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.RevertExistingImpersonation () [0x0000f] in :0 
  at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter.ProcessLog (Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogEntry log, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventCache traceEventCache) [0x00000] in :0

### at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.LogWriter+<>c__DisplayClass13.b__12 () [0x0007f] in :0

From The log, you can clearly see that System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent breaks the rule...

Could you Kindly help me on this?
Did anyone try to use Enterprise Library with Mono on MacOS?
Is somewhere present a workaround?

Thanks a lot for your help and time.
Regards,

Comment: That library is 6+ year old and is no longer supported/maintained by Microsoft, the source code is available on github in an archive repo if you want to clone it and mod it for your project...

Comment: So you know it is `WindowsIdentity`, and EF 6 is Windows only. Mono won't help you magically fill any gap on non-Windows platforms.

Comment: @SushiHangover: yes I know that is 6+ year old... issue is not on MEL library but on mscorlib.dll developed for mono... that currently is a new Microsoft product and it should be maintained...

Comment: @Lex Li: yes that’s correct what you say but I thought that could fix this to maintain some previous compatibility... probably they do not even know...or probably there is a different method to use to avoid such issue... that’s the purpose of my question... to find a fix (if any) or, a valid alternative (if exists)!

Comment: https://github.com/Chavoshi/EnterpriseLibrary.NetCore + .NET Core might be your only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have managed such situation.
First of all, thanks to all comments, those helped me lot of with resolution.
Basically, i had to change a part of MEL 6 code and then i could use it without issue.

As previously suggested by @SushiHangover, i took MEL 6 source code and i started to analyze... i have fould a part of the code that was calling `SecurityIdentifier User` inside mscorlib.dll

What i did is:
- download MEL 6 source code
- open it with Visual Studio for MAC
- delete all Test projects and files not supported by the engine
- compile till everything is fine

Once you have your prj compiled, find and comment "Impersonation" section of the below section:

```
private void ProcessLog(LogEntry log, TraceEventCache traceEventCache)
    {
        // revert any outstanding impersonation
        //using (RevertExistingImpersonation())
        //{
            var items = new ContextItems();
            items.ProcessContextItems(log);

            var matchingTraceSources = GetMatchingTraceSources(log);
            var traceListenerFilter = new TraceListenerFilter();

            foreach (LogSource traceSource in matchingTraceSources)
            {
                traceSource.TraceData(log.Severity, log.EventId, log, traceListenerFilter, traceEventCache, ReportExceptionDuringTracing);
            }
        //}
    }
```

[Code Sample Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBOrM.png)

After that, recompile, use compiled dll into your own project and it will finally work.

If you have any further question or dubt, please let me know and i will be happy to reply.

Have a great working day,
Regards,

Florin